# Getting Started With Android & JSOUP

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, jsoup

I am currently attempting to make an Android application and have come to the conclusion that I must use JSOUP to finish it. I am using JSOUP to extract data from the Internet and then post it on my app.

What I am trying to figure out is how to extract multiple bits of data from the url and then use each one of them inside of their own XML String TextView (If that is correct?)

Here is a snipbit of the HTML I am trying to extract.

---

a href="http://www.campusdish.com/en-US/CSMA/OldDominion/Locations/rda.aspx?RCN=m12296&MI=122&RN=BACoN  TURKEY  SLICED" OnCick="javascript: NewWindow('http://www.campusdish.com/en-US/CSMA/OldDominion/Locations/rda.aspx?RCN=m12296&MI=122&RN=BACON  TURKEY  SLICED', 'RDA_window',  'width=450, height=600, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no,  directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, copyhistory=no');return false" Class="recipeLink">BACON  TURKEY  SLICED

---

I am trying to extract the words *BACON  TURKEY  SLICED*

The problem is I do not understand JSOUP at all. Like I have an idea about it but I can't seem to practically use it and all that. I was wondering if someone could try and give me a push in the right direction.

Also, I have tried reading the cookbook to no prevail.

If anyone could help, thank you so much!

### EDIT

Here are two more. I believe they are the exact same thing.

a href="http://www.campusdish.com/en-US/CSMA/OldDominion/Locations/rda.aspx?RCN=m4903&MI=122&RN=STATION  OMELET" OnClick="javascript: NewWindow('http://www.campusdish.com/en-US/CSMA/OldDominion/Locations/rda.aspx?RCN=m4903&MI=122&RN=STATION  OMELET', 'RDA_window',  'width=450, height=600, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no,  directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, copyhistory=no');return false" Class="recipeLink">STATION  OMELET

a href="http://www.campusdish.com/en-US/CSMA/OldDominion/Locations/rda.aspx?RCN=m784&MI=122&RN=CEREAL  HOT  GRITS" OnClick="javascript: NewWindow('http://www.campusdish.com/en-US/CSMA/OldDominion/Locations/rda.aspx?RCN=m784&MI=122&RN=CEREAL  HOT  GRITS', 'RDA_window',  'width=450, height=600, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no,  directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, copyhistory=no');return false" Class="recipeLink">CEREAL  HOT  GRITS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this answer is going to assume that you are interested in:

- <a href=".." >TEXT YOU WANT</a>
- All these <a> tags have the `style` attribute "recipeLink".

Given your example, here as a String:

```
String tastyTurkeySandwich= "<a href=\"http://www.campusdish.com/en-US/CSMA/OldDominion/Locations/rda.aspx?RCN=m12296&amp;MI=122&amp;RN=BACoN  TURKEY  SLICED\" OnCick=\"javascript: NewWindow('http://www.campusdish.com/en-US/CSMA/OldDominion/Locations/rda.aspx?RCN=m12296&amp;MI=122&amp;RN=BACON  TURKEY  SLICED', 'RDA_window',  'width=450, height=600, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no,  directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, copyhistory=no');return false\" Class=\"recipeLink\">BACON  TURKEY  SLICED</a>";
```

You can extract the (first) text with the following code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(tastyTurkeySandwich);
Elements links = doc.select("a[href].recipeLink");
// This will just print the text in the first one
System.out.println(links.first().text());
```

To iterate over an `Elements` (which implements the `Iterable` interface) instance:

```
for (Element link : links) {
    // Calling link.text() will return BACON TURKEY SLICED etc. etc.
    System.out.println(link.text());
}
```

In short:

1. `a[href]` will match all the <a> tags that have a href attribute.
2. the `.recipeLink` part will filter that selection to only include links that have the recipeLink style.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! This helped out a whole lot! How would I extract the rest of the segments that are almost identical to this one (The only changes are that the food item).   There are about 4 more that I would need to extract. I can't just make them Strings by hard coding it, because it is going to update daily.

Comment: Well, what common attributes does these links share? Edit your question and add those 4 others?

Comment: I just added a two more to the top of this page. The exact same thing just with different food items.

Comment: Both have the same style attribute (receipeLink) - if you fed the entire documents with all these links into the example above the `Elements links` variable would allow you to find each and every one.

Comment: So are you saying to do this:

1. Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url);
   Element lins = doc.select("a[href].recipeLink");


OR

2. String tastyTurkeySandwich = " THE ENTIRE WEBSITE SOURCE CODE THAT I COPIED AND PASTED ";

Comment: `Jsoup#parse(String)` expects a HTML document in the parameter. If you want Jsoup to download **and** parse the document for you consider using `Jsoup#connect(String)` or just calling `Jsoup#parse(java.net.URL,int)`.

Comment: So I think the way for me to go would be by using the JSOUP parser by using the url of the website so that way it would update it accordingly (when the site updates regularly). Is that a step in the right direction? And thank you again for your advice!